# join axes in barplot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to eliminate the gap between the `x` and `y` axes in `barplot` and extend the predicted line back to intersect the `y` axis, preferably in base `R`.  Is this possible?  Thank you for any advice or suggestions.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
   band  mid.point  count   
     1      0.5       74
     2      1.5       73
     3      2.5       79
     4      3.5       70
     5      4.5       78
     6      5.5       63
     7      6.5       59
     8      7.5       60
', header = TRUE)
my.data

x <- my.data$mid.point^2

my.model <- lm(count ~ x, data = my.data)

my.plot <- barplot(my.data$count, ylim=c(0,100), space=0, col=NA)
axis(1, at=my.plot+0.5, labels=my.data$band)
lines(predict(my.model, data.frame(x=x), type="resp"), col="black", lwd = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: add `xaxs = 'i'` inside barplot. is that what you are asking? As for the line, it is predicting for the data you supplied, ie, `x`

Comment: @rawr Thanks.  I tried using `x=c(0,x)` before posting and instead of extending the line to the y axis it changed the slope of the existing line.  I should have mentioned that in my post.  The `xaxs` command was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT November 26, 2014**

I just realized the two plots are not the same (the plot in the original post and the plot in my answer below).  Compare the two curved lines closely, particularly at the right-side of the plot.  Clearly the two curved lines intersect the top of the 8th bar in different locations.  However, I have not yet had time to figure out why the plots differ.

---

Here is one way to extrapolate the predicted line back to the y axis.  I incorporate rawr's suggestion regarding eliminating the gap between the y axis and the x axis.

```
setwd('c:/users/markm/simple R programs/')

jpeg(filename = "barplot_and_line.jpeg")

my.data <- read.table(text = '
   band  mid.point  count   
     1      0.5       74
     2      1.5       73
     3      2.5       79
     4      3.5       70
     5      4.5       78
     6      5.5       63
     7      6.5       59
     8      7.5       60
', header = TRUE)

x <- my.data$mid.point^2

my.model <- lm(count ~ x, data = my.data)

z <- seq(0,8,0.01)
y <- my.model$coef[1] + my.model$coef[2] * z^2

barplot(my.data$count, ylim=c(0,100), space=0, col=NA, xaxs = 'i')
points(z, y, type='l', col=1)

dev.off()
```

[image]